# Incorrect DIV height in IE only if app accessed with server name

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have very strange problem specific to IE (confirmed in v8 and v9).
When using jquery to determine div height with:

```js
$('#sys_MainPage').height()
```

This code returns cca. 260 in Chrome, Firefox and IE (only if I access application using IP address). But, if I access application using server name and IE 8/9, calculated height is 853?

I'm using jquery 1.4.2.

What could be the cause? Is there any proper reason for this weird behaviour?

**EDIT:**
Problem is caused with different compatibility modes:
Site is accessed using IP address: 
Browser mode: IE8
Document mode: IE8 standards

Using server name: 
Browser mode: IE8 compat view
Document mode: IE7 standards

I solved this with web.config edit but I still don't understand why is browser/document mode different depending on entered url?

Comment: Can you confirm if the site is running in compatability mode for IE8/9 either using IP address or by using server name?

Comment: @rangitatanz You were right about cause of problem, please look at my edit. Do you know what is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is switching to compatability mode when it is being viewed from one of these locations.

You can find a way here [Force IE8 *not* to use Compatibility View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064702/force-ie8-not-to-use-compatibility-view) to force it not to switch. However I would still test this in IE7 and make sure that it is not broken for that.

Pretty much what you need to specify is this:

> You can override this behavior by using a meta element to specify an X-UA-Compatible      http-equiv header, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > or 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

As for why it is broken - we would need to look at the site to do that there are hundreds of reasons why.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. With one minor difference, I set application wide X-UA-Compatible header in my web.config.

Comment: Awesome - yeah I am doddery and forgot that!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without your CSS/HTML, but try:

```
.outerHeight()
```

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without source code.
First use the ie's debbuger and check why the height is so big. 
Maybe a css bug of ie is causing this.

Second try setting your height on windows load event

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    alert($('#sys_MainPage').height());
 });
```