# X-UA-Compatible priority: response headers vs meta

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, http-headers, compatibility, meta-tags

What declaration would have priority? Passed in with server resonse header like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018834/1039816) or with HTML meta tag like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014693/1039816)

Problem is that clien's proxy server is forcing IE to work in IE7 mode by adding responce headers. I want to override this with meta tag. Will this work? I can't test, as I don't have access to client's proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which X-UA-Compatible takes precedence? Http-header or Meta-tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128739/which-x-ua-compatible-takes-precedence-http-header-or-meta-tags)

Answer (score 0):

The meta tag always has [higher priority](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications.aspx).