# IE11 switching to Document Mode: IE7 Standards

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

IE11 switching to Document Mode: IE7 Standards
Use

1. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`
2. Tools > Compatibility View settings.

but not take effect.
How to force document mode IE=11 / IE=Edge with programmatically at Client 3?
[image]

Comment: Note that the meta tag must be the first line after your head tag,Is it that way?

Comment: yes, already meta tag at first line after head but not effect

Comment: Could you give your head tag completely as it is with your question?

Comment: 1. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: I meant your head tag i.e. everything between <head></head>.

Comment: `<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="../css/StyleGTIE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>`

Comment: See my answer below.You need to use meta tag just after doctype.

Comment: '<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<html>
<head runat="server">'

Comment: @Ash : no that doesn't work,please check that happening image

Comment: Sorry images are blocked at my place.Will check up on this later.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a .htaccess file?
I always use the htaccess solution for this.

Not my answer, if you can use htaccess.
See: [Force IE8 *not* to use Compatibility View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064702/force-ie8-not-to-use-compatibility-view)

anwser is beneath this line, from that post

---

You can also set the X-UA-Compatible header in Apache, via the config or an .htaccess file using the code below. Credit goes to html5boilerplate.com

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Better website experience for IE users
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
# github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
# Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    BrowserMatch MSIE ie
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#
# Because X-UA-Compatible isn't sent to non-IE (to save header bytes), we need to inform proxies that content changes based on UA
#
  Header append Vary User-Agent
# Cache control is set only if mod_headers is enabled, so that's unncessary to declare
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use one of the following meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

and/or

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=7" >
```

Or check this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely your doctype is incorrect.
Once this will be fixed/added it should take the latest one by default

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this i.e. use meta tag outside head and just below doctype:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@HttpContext.Current.Cache["application_title"].ToString()</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```